# SecurityException on Samsung Galaxy S8 devices

Tags: android, crashlytics

A specific userbase of our `Android` app experiences the following crash according to `Crashlytics`.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bundle.id/com.bundle.id.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10346 cannot get secrets for accounts of type: com.osp.app.signin
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

We have googled, searched, tried to reproduce without any success. According to Crashlytics it only happens on the Samsung Galaxy S8 devices.

We have tested with one but it worked just fine. Has anyone seen this error before or knows what can cause this? It is really frustrating.

Comment: https://www.nowsecure.com/blog/2015/01/26/samsung-account-and-galaxy-apps-technical-breakdown-cve-2015-0863-and-cve-2015-0864/

Comment: But how can I, as a developer, fix this issue? @GokulNathKP

Comment: @Reshad did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: I think the issue was solved but I can't really remember how.. sorry @Eric

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what OP's issue was, but I was running into the same crash, and it turns out the issue is that I was getting the `Account` object from `addOnAccountsUpdatedListener`.  On most devices, the list you get from that API is filtered by your accountType.  On some Samsung devices, it also includes the Samsung account on your phone, if one is set.  Workaround:

```
    accountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener({ accounts ->
      // Samsung is great: it sends us updates on Samsung accounts even though the accountType
      // doesn't match.
      val ourUpdatedAccounts = accounts.filter { account -> account.type == myAccountType }
      // do something with ourUpdatedAccounts
    }, Handler(), false)
```

Comment: Thanks, this one was a hard to find answer!